# I want to write some css for changing a toggle plus sign colour

Tags: css

I have a Wordpress theme I am trying to customise. I would like to change the colour of my toggle plus signs to white in CSS but I can't work it out. If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it.

This is the URL:
http://dev3.runforthehills.com/wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2Fpost.php%3Fpost%3D74%26action%3Dedit

This is the CSS I tried to write:

```
.toggles .icon-plus-sign:before { color:#ffffff; !important;}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have `;` before `!important;` when it should not be there. 
Also your URL is not accessible as an admin URL.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and not a link to your site or any other third party site. And a perfect example of why is that your link now requires a login and makes this question, along with any answers, useless to anyone else.

Comment: Hi @Rob. I don't really know what is meant by a minimal reproducible example here? I'm sorry I am new to this site. How do you mean my link requires a login? I didn't;t mean to ask the question wrongly, it's just a bit confusing

Comment: Read the link to the SO rules I posted. You must post the markup here that we can copy and reproduce your problem. You didn't do that and this question, along with the answer, will eventually be closed and deleted (unless you do it now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set background color for it:

```
.toggles .icon-plus-sign:before { background-color:#ffffff !important;}
```

As you see below it changes nicely!

[image]

Edit: also Ihave set background color for ::after property.

Comment: Yay, thanks so much for this Saeed. this worked.
Would you also be able to tell me the css t change the circle outline colour and the dividing line between the sections?

Comment: The outline circle is "border" of the "icon-plus-sign" element. so we can change the color by 'border-color' property. example:

    border-color: #fff !important;

And the dividing lines color could be changed as below:

    .toggles .toggle {border-bottom-color: #fff;}

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks so much for taking the time to reply. Hope you have a good day!

Comment: Do I have to do anything to give you credits or thanks or anything? Really unsure how this website works.

Comment: No need to appreciate. But I'm available if your website may have problems I will help you fix it @Connie